# Scala - how to assign entry numbers to sorted elements of a collection?

Tags: scala, collections

I wanted to write a method to process sales data in a way that the sales are sorted by date and concatenated with an entry number and a sale type like this:

`0/2018-05-02 01:55:07/Sale type A,1/2018-09-22 02:55:07/Sale type B`

But for now I could only achieve concatenating saleDate and saleType. How is it possible to produce an entry number for each record? By entry number I mean the order of sales after sorting by date

```
def concatSales(sales: Seq[Sale]): Seq[String] = {
        sales
        .sortWith(_.saleDate < _.saleDate)
        .map(sale => s"$DELIMITER${sale.saleDate}$DELIMITER${sale.saleType}")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by entry number ?

Comment: does Sale class have entryNumber fields or so?

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar by entry number I mean the order of sales after sorting by date

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign an index for each element, you can use `zipWithIndex`:

```
sales
  .sortWith(_.saleDate < _.saleDate)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map {
    case (sale, idx) => s"$idx: ..."
  }
```

Note that you might want to use `.sortBy` instead of `.sortWith` since it looks simpler:

```
 sales.sortBy(_.saleDate)
```